# Creating two equidistant edges (two "centered" edge loops)

Tags: modeling, edges

It's easier to explain what I'm trying to do with pictures.

I have this structure:
[image: what I have]

And I want to achieve this:
[image: What I want]

such that those two new edges are equidistant from the first, and the distance is set precisely (using the keyboard).

I've been doing this using two `Edge Loop (Ctrl-R)`, but I need to do the math by hand, since it always counts the cut distance from the left. Is there a easier way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and then scroll (You can add more cuts that way):

[image]

You can fine tune the distance in the operator panel <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise The Bevel, Vertex/Face/Edge snapping, and Looptools addon are the three most under usedmodeling tools in blender.